# Is regularity usually preserved by adding a constant to the polynomials cutting out an affine variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

More explicitly, my question is: if $Y$ is a regular affine variety cut out by $(P_1,\dots,P_r) \subseteq k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$, is the affine variety $Y_d$ cut out by $(P_1+d,\dots,P_r+d)$ regular for almost all $d \in k$ (whatever "almost all" means in this context)? Of course the Jacobian matrix has the same polynomial entries (because the partial derivatives don't care about constants), but they are evaluated at different points of $k^n$, so that I cannot see any obvious reason why this should be true. My motivation comes from easy examples like the circle $X^2+Y^2+d$, that is regular except for $d=0$.

Comment: This is certainly correct if codimension of $Y$ is $r$ by generic smoothness.

Comment: @Mohan could you please elaborate? I don't understand what you mean

Comment: @Mohan: I think one needs more than generic smoothness to conclude because the schemes are not projective. What might happen is that the singular locus of $Y_d$ "moves to infinity" at $d = 0$ (and hence $Y_0$ is the only regular fiber), and one would have to carefully study this special situation to exclude that.

Comment: @Mohan Actually, in the original problem I had projective varieties. My *real* question is whether **the reduction modulo $p$ of a regular projective curve can only become singular for finitely many primes**. The above question was only a specific (probably useless) attempt to go around an issue, but if you have general advice or references, it is very welcome!

Comment: @Johann Haas Sorry, I have misread, probably the above comment was to be addressed to you too